# Using JavaScript how to insert blank <TD> tag between existing <TD> of a row?

Tags: javascript

Here is my table,

```
<tr>
<td>One</td>
<td>Two</td>
<td>Three</td>
<td>Four</td>
</tr>
```

Using JavaScript I need to insert `<TD>` between existing columns like,

```
<tr>
<td>One</td>
<td></td>
<td>Two</td>
<td></td>
<td>Three</td>
<td></td>
<td>Four</td>
</tr>
```

I'm using following code,

```
var trNodes = tBody.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    var tRows, tColumns, i = 0, columnLength;
    columnLengh = trNodes.length;
    while (tRows = trNodes[i++]) {
        var tD = document.createElement('TD');
        tColumns = tRows.getElementsByTagName('TD');
        columnLength = tColumns.length;
        if (columnLength >= 2) {
            for (var iCol = 0; iCol < tColumns.length; iCol++) {
                tColumns[iCol].parentNode.insertBefore(tD, tColumns[iCol].nextSibling);
            }
        }
    }
```

Its creating the nodes at the end but not in between as mentioned below :(

```
 <tr>
<td>One</td>    
<td>Two</td>    
<td>Three</td>
<td></td><td></td><td></td>
<td>Four</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is your attempt so far?

Comment: Doesn't the `insertBefore()` method do what you want?

Comment: I just removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your allowed to use jquery you can do this

```
$('td').prev().after('<td>test</td>');
```

To get this working on a specific table give your tables an id and select like this

```
$('#tableName td').prev().after('<td>test</td>');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NH2J2/2/)

Comment: @btoueg fixed - and of course your right on the Jquery as I said so myself

Comment: Morten Anderson - Worked fine. But, it should be applied only for a specific table in the HTML not for all.

Comment: Morten Anderson -Is it possible to apply only for selected/highlighted table?

Answer (score 0):

Using This you can create a  `var td = document.createElement('td');` Then append it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the below code:

`$('#tablename tr td:nth-child(N)').after('< td> < /td> ')`

Here for `N` you may use the value such as 1 , 3 ..etc depending on your number of `td` present in your row