# How to create dummy TD of table to give space between two TD elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building the multiple TD's in single TR of table dynamically.
Now I am looking to give some space between two TD elements data.
Could anyone tell me how to create dummy TD dynamically which gives space between two TD's.
Below are two TD's.

```
        var td31 = document.createElement('td');
        var imgShare = document.createElement("img");
        imgShare.src = "xyz.jpeg";
        imgShare.id = "image/"+allSharedMediaList[i][2];
        imgShare.height = '15';
        imgShare.width = '15';
        imgShare.addEventListener("click", shareImage);
        td31.appendChild(imgShare);

        //I WANT TO BUILD DUMMY TD here TO GIVE SPAVE BETWEEN TWO TD'S

        var td32 = document.createElement('td');
        var likeCount = document.createElement("span");
        likeCount.id = "likecount"+allSharedMediaList[i][2];
        likeCount.name= "likecount";
        likeCount.textContent = allSharedMediaList[i][3]+" Likes ";
        td32.appendChild(likeCount);
```

Comment: See the [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) property. Or, simply use some padding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JavaScript how to insert blank <TD> tag between existing <TD> of a row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656667/using-javascript-how-to-insert-blank-td-tag-between-existing-td-of-a-row)

Comment: I want to add dummy TD to get space between two TD's, above link is explaining how to add dummy TD but not the space..!!!